# Collision detection for side scroller 2d game, mario tile based

Tags: java, collision, slick2d, 2d-games

Alright so I am making a 2d side scroller. And I am doing a block system like mario.
I want to know if it is alright to have 4 lines as a player: Head, Right side, Left side, Feet.
And have a method check if rightside.intersects block Is that a good way to do this?
for collision detection.
I tried doing collision by rectangle and rectangle but it was a problem because I have to check the ground if the player touches the top of the ground then stop moving downward with gravity but when I went to check if the player hit a block on the side, the player would already send a signal saying that it hit it even though it did not, the reason it was because it was hitting the ground.

Any Ideas how I can do simple collision by block and player? There are not hills or slants in the game. This is coded in Java by the way.

Also I heard about the point method but it just did not seem good for this because I am using rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to bound the player using a [Rectangle](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/geom/Rectangle.html) and use another Rectangle for the tile, they have a `.intersects` method you can use for collision.

Comment: I am but the problem is that when I check collision it checks ground and then I can't check the sides because the value is already true.

Answer (score 0):

as arynaq said you could have a bounding box but have it check horizontal and vertical collision separately, that way you could handle your types of collisions differently. Or you could make more specific checks suck as .headCollided or .feetCollided that only check if one side is colliding.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check at least 8 points around the character, one on each corner and one in the middle of each edge of the bounding rectangle. I'd start with the one directly below the player character and test it out, then add all the other ones once you see what behaviour results in not having them, ie. falling off an edge too early, walking through walls etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a physics engine to leverage collision detection and such, you could use jBox2D, integrate it with Slick2D, jBox2D will provide collision callbacks where you can get more fined definitions about that particular detection.

You can get jBox2D (a port from the original Box2D C++ physics simulator) here:

http://www.jbox2d.org/

You can learn more about box2D here: (this tutorials are for ActionScript but they are incredibly similar, and he (Todd Kerpelman) debates some game architectural issues so it's really helpful).

http://www.kerp.net/box2d/